# How to find All Graphic Cards?

Tags: c#, graphics, nvidia, diagnostics, vga

I used this code for finding graphic cards:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
               new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration");

string graphicsCard = "";
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
   foreach (PropertyData property in mo.Properties)
   {
      if (property.Name == "Description")
      {
        graphicsCard += property.Value.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

[image: My Graphic Cards]

but result is: Nvidia Quadro K6000

How to find all Graphic cards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The very first line of [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394137(v=vs.85).aspx) reads:

> [The Win32_DisplayConfiguration WMI class is no longer available for use as of Windows Server 2008. Instead, use the properties in the Win32_VideoController, Win32_DesktopMonitor, and CIM_VideoControllerResolution classes.]

So I suggest you start out with [Win32_VideoController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx).